# cannot insert NULL into ("STUDENT"."RATING"."RATING_AGENCY_ID")

Tags: sql

So I am using a text editor for SQL and I don't know how to fix this problem. I create a table and try to insert some new data and then I get this error and I really don't know what it means.

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("STUDENT"."RATING"."RATING_AGENCY_ID")

```
 create table rating (
    rating_id NUMBER
,   rating_agency_id varchar2(150) constraint nn_rating_1 NOT NULL
,   rating varchar2(150)           constraint nn_rating_2 NOT NULL
,   description varchar2(420)      constraint nn_rating_3 NOT NULL
,   created_by   Number            constraint nn_rating_4 NOT NULL
,   creation_date date             constraint nn_rating_5 NOT NULL
,   last_updated_by number         constraint nn_rating_6 NOT NULL
,   last_update_date varchar2(45)  constraint nn_rating_7 NOT NULL
,   constraint pk_rating Primary key(rating_id)
,   constraint uq_rating  unique(rating)
,   constraint fk_rating_1 foreign key(created_by) references system_user(system_user_id)
,   constraint fk_rating_2 foreign key(last_updated_by) references system_user(system_user_id) 
);

CREATE SEQUENCE rating_s1
START WITH 1000
INCREMENT BY 1;

INSERT INTO rating
(rating_id, rating_agency_id, rating, description, created_by, creation_date,
last_updated_by, last_update_date)
VALUES
(rating_s1.NEXTVAL, (SELECT rating_agency_id FROM rating_agency WHERE
rating_agency_abbr = 'ESRB'), 'EC', 'Early Childhood', (SELECT system_user_id FROM
system_user WHERE system_user_name = 'DBA2'), SYSDATE, (SELECT system_user_id FROM
system_user WHERE system_user_name = 'DBA2'), SYSDATE);
```

The solutions I have seen are in Microsoft SQL server management and they change IDdetail() can I do that
manually with code or is there another solution. I am really new to SQL so I only kind of know what I am doing.

Comment: Looks like there is no `rating_agency` whose `rating_agency_abbr` is equal to `'ESRB'`. Check your data.

Comment: ok thanks I'll look into it.

Comment: try this:  SELECT count(rating_agency_id) FROM rating_agency WHERE
rating_agency_abbr = 'ESRB'

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Query:

```
(SELECT rating_agency_id FROM rating_agency WHERE rating_agency_abbr = 'ESRB')
```

is returning null, so you need either correcting `rating_agency_abbr = 'ESRB'` or you need to set the default value when it is null.